# Determine if $\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $k$ be a real number. Define $f\colon\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^ky}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$},\\k-2&\text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}.\end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Find the value of $k$ such that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
> 2. For the value of $k$ found in part (1), determine whether $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.
>
> [(Image that replaced text.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCWEg.png)

So, I have solved the part (1) and found that the $k=2$.
Then both partial derivatives $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ of the function $f(x,y)$ equal $0$.

I know that if the partial derivatives exist and continuous at $(0,0)$, then the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

However, I also know that we can check the differentiability using this formula:

> **Definition.** Let $f\colon X\to\Bbb{R}$ where $X\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ is open, and let $\mathbf{a}\in X$. Suppose $f_x(\mathbf{a}),f_y(\mathbf{a})$ exist. We say that *$f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{a}$* if $$\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})-[f(\mathbf{a})+f_x(\mathbf{a})(x_1-a_1)+f_y(\mathbf{a})(x_2-a_2)]}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|}=0.$$
>
> [(Image that replaced text.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKfSU.png)

And using, this formula I get that it is not continuous at $(0,0)$ (I have used $x=r\cos\alpha$ and $y = r\sin\alpha$ substitution to check it.)

Can you please tell me which approach is right, and is the function differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $k=2$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!!

Comment: Yes, $k=2$ is correct. You mean to say that $f$ is not *differentiable* at $(0,0)$? Please show the details of how you showed that limit is not $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to check whether

$$0 = \lim_{(a_1,a_2) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(a_1,a_2)}{\|(a_1, a_2)\|} = \lim_{(a_1,a_2) \to (0,0)} \frac{a_1^2a_2}{(a_1^2+a_2^2)^{3/2}}$$

If we approach $0$ along the line $y = x$ in the first quadrant, we get

$$\frac{f(t,t)}{\|(t,t)\|} = \frac{t^3}{(2t^2)^{3/2}} = \frac1{2^{3/2}}$$

which doesn't converge to $0$ as $t \to 0^+$ and therefore the above limit is not $0$.

We conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.